# Performing layer 7 health check with HAProxy and uWSGI in Django application

Tags: django, uwsgi, haproxy, high-availability

I'm using this `uwsgi.ini` to run a `Django` application.

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :8000
enable-proxy-protocol = true
chdir = /usr/local/src/api
module = api.wsgi
uid = root
gid = root
pidfile = /var/run/api-uwsgi.pid
master = true
processes = 10
chmod-socket = 664
threaded-logger = true
logto = /var/log/api/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize = 10000000
logfile-chown = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

I've added an API url to perform database and cache health checks under the `/health-check` url. This API returns status code 200 if everything is fine. Now I want to be able to health check in layer 7 using this API with `HAProxy` but using `option httpchk` the response status code is 301, so the health check fails. Here is the backend part of my `HAProxy` config.

```
backend http_server
  mode http
  balance leastconn
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  option httpchk
  http-check send meth GET uri /health-check ver HTTP/1.1 hdr Accept application\json
  http-check expect rstatus 200
  server app1 192.168.0.11:8000 check inter 500 downinter 5s fall 2 rise 3
  server app2 192.168.0.12:8000 check inter 500 downinter 5s fall 2 rise 3
```

Here is the result of running the `Django` apps with `uWSGI` and `HAProxy`. Note that the health check on layer 4 is working as expected.

```
Server http_server/app2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 301, info: "Moved Permanently", check duration: 54ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

So what is causing this problem and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two steps to solve this problem:

1. If no url route matches with the requested one `Django`'s `APPEND_SLASH` setting appends a `/` to to end of the url and performs a 301 redirect on that. I've used `/health-check` instead of `/health-check/` so the request was redirected from `/health-check` to `/health-check/`
2. The `hdr` option of `http-check` accepts a key and a value. For the `accept` header the value must be inside quotes so `hdr Accept application\json` becomes `hdr accept "application/json"`

Here is the final and working part of the backend config:

```
backend http_server
  mode http
  balance leastconn
  option forwardfor
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  option httpchk
  http-check send meth GET uri /health-check/ ver HTTP/1.1 hdr accept "application/json"
  http-check expect rstatus 200
  server 192.168.0.11:8000 check inter 500 downinter 2s fall 2 rise 3
  server 192.168.0.12:8000 check inter 500 downinter 2s fall 2 rise 3
```